# WAMP's PHP print empty array - error_log

Tags: php, angularjs, wamp

I am using WAMP to deal with my PHP and MySql.

In my PHP code, I did this:

```
error_log(print_r($_GET, true));
```

What I see in the error_log is this:

```
[20-Jan-2015 18:30:30 UTC] Array ( )
```

I know there is something in my $_GET request because the rest of the PHP code do what it needs to do.

I also try to print an SQL string later and this is working.

Just in case, I even did this in the php.ini file:

```
log_errors_max_len = 0
```

Anyone knows why I have empty Array?

******* UPDATE *********

I finally figured out why I was not seeing anything. I was not sending any parameters for a specific $http (angularJS) request!!!

Comment: if you try to var_dump it at the same location as you error_log does it return the same output?

Comment: I tried "var_dump($_GET)", nothing happened. I tried error_log(var_dump($_GET)) and only saw timestamp. Did I use that function correctly?

Comment: something tells me that somewhere in your code you set `$_GET = [];` or `$_GET = Array();`

Comment: see update above. I am not really proud of me!